# TF: memory allocation error if two GPU present

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, gpu

I have 2 GPUs installed in two pciex16 slots. One is 1080Ti, one is 980.

GPU-Z shows both devices present and device manager says both device are operating normally. This is a windows server 2012 OS.

If only one of the devices is enabled (via the device manager I disable one) I can run

```
from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
local_device_protos = device_lib.list_local_devices()
```

and see GPU:0 device. It works for both the 980 and the 1080ti. I am able to run other TF code and it uses the GPU correctly.

If BOTH of the devices are enabled, if I run this code I get the following CUDA out of memory error:

```
InternalError: failed initializing StreamExecutor for CUDA device ordinal 1: Internal: failed call to cuDevicePrimaryCtxRetain: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY; total memory reported: 4294967296
```

Despite GPU-Z showing that the 980 memory usage is 0.

If I run `sess = tf.Session()` I get "failed to create session" error.

Finally, if I run any of the two commands twice, the python process dies (python has stopped working pop-up).

I tried running with lower memory fraction

```
gpu_fraction = 0.1
gpu_options = tf.GPUOptions(per_process_gpu_memory_fraction=gpu_fraction)
sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(gpu_options=gpu_options))
```

But this sessions fails to start as well.

What is the cause of these errors? I don't actually care about having both gpu's available to a particular python process, however I do want to be able to have two different python process use one of the gpus each.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:

just to add code like this fails to create session for either gpus if both gpus are enabled.

```
with tf.device("/gpu:1"):
    sess2=tf.Session()
```

Edit2:

as per @RobertCrovella 's suggestion, `os.putenv('CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES','1') or '0'` allowed me to run code successfully on a single gpu per process.

Edit3:

using the cuda_visible_devices to run tf causes the gpu-z to show incorrect memory usage (it shows as 0).

Comment: `I do want to be able to have two different python process use one of the gpus each` - use the CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES [environment variable](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#env-vars) to select one GPU for each process.

Comment: OK, i will try that, but when i had tf.device option it still failed.

Comment: @RobertCrovella doing os.putenv('CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES','0') or '1' worked. Still curious about the original error.